# How do I recover deleted data lost in a hacked Facebook account?

Tags: facebook

We believe that my friend's Facebook account recently got hacked. She was browsing on it one second, suddenly got kicked out and could not log back in. We have reset the password since then and regained access to the account, but it has been wiped out. It's not just like a brand new account, completely blank.

Any ideas on how to get the content back? How to contact Facebook? I've been browsing their Help section, but haven't found an email address or any form to contact them regarding this matter.

Comment: @wizlog OK thanks. Should I copy paste the question over there, or anything else I should do?

Comment: thanks Tom. yeah I just enabled something like that feature although not involving a mobile phone, but through email instead. First of all I want to know how this was done though. Is there actually a button somewhere that will delete all your content? If so, is there a way to undo it? because Facebook does not delete anything as we know. the most they do is disassociate content from a user's profile. Want to ask someone from Facebook about this.

Comment: @rabbid - I'd contact Facebook directly rather than going through Stack Exchange in the hope that someone knows the answer.

Comment: *> Is there actually a button somewhere that will delete all your content?* — No, of course not, it's Facebook. Under European law, for example, they're forced to delete your stuff if you ask for it, but who is going to prove to you that they've deleted is?

Comment: @ChrisF yes I am trying to do just that, but I've been to their Help page and have found no email address nor anything else that can put me in direct touch with them. Can you guys help?

Comment: Which country are you from?

Comment: USA, but I am currently in Indonesia.

Comment: Hm, here's their [data use policy](https://www.facebook.com/full_data_use_policy). Here's the link for [deleting your account](https://www.facebook.com/about/privacy/your-info#deleting).

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue in 2006. Don't know if it still works but the team running privacy@facebook.com were able to sort me out.